# Tree graphs maximum degree 2?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

With a non-isomorphic tree with 7 vertices, if each vertices has at most 2 degree. Wouldn't the number of trees that follow this condition be just 1?

The tree in a row juggles between 1 and 2 degrees already, however if you move any of the vertices around, it will always trigger a degree 3.

Just making sure I'm on point, or am I wrong?

Comment: This is correct, but if one enhances the structure under consideration (e.g., by instead considering rooted trees) one gets more than one isomorphism type.

Comment: And trees cannot be disconnected, correct?

Comment: Correct: One definition of tree is a graph such that, for any two vertices, there is a unique path connecting them (and which uses no edge more than once). Appropriately, a disjoint union of trees is sometimes called a *forest*.

Comment: Thank you for the verification of my thought process. Appreciated

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.